# Bootstrap - How can I add space between cards

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to put space between my cards.

I have 4 cards next to each other. But when I use `mr-3` on the card divs, the last card goes below. I don't want that to happen.

How can keep all 4 cards with spaces between them and in the same row / line ?

I also tried `d-flex justify-content-around` but it doesn't work.

Below is my code

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="card col-md-3">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-md-3">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-md-3">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-md-3">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

First image :
[image]

Second image where last card goes below :
[image]

Comment: Couldn't you use [`.card-columns`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-columns), [`.card-deck`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-decks) or [`.card-group`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-groups) ?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/card/#grid-cards

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I didn't know this ones. I will try them , thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

just put the card in a col...then try

cards,card-deck,card-colums dont have the responsive feature

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).